# Email status displays "Read" instead of "new" for all received emails in case object

Tags: email2case

Whenever a case is opened,Email status displays "Read" instead of "new" for all received emails in case object. New emails are also displayed as read.

Comment: Should we assume your question is how to have new emails to have the status "new", or will you include it in your post ? The more effort you put in a question, the better the answers will be. Have you already investigated certain things ? What have you already tried so far, ..... help us help you.

Comment: Yes, some information on your configuration would be useful too. Do you have any workflow or triggers on cases or emailMessages?

Comment: In Email to Case Setup, a case is created when new email is received.
However, the status of these email messages is always'Read'  & never 'New' .

Interestingly, If we check status of Email using Dev Console-SOQL query, status of email defaulted to 'New' but is changed to 'Read' as soon as user clicks on Case record in Salesforce though he is yet to click on 'Email Message' record.

Comment: Yes,I have a trigger on EmailMessage object but even if I make the trigger Inactive,the problem still remains.